# IE8 opacity/filter css style not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have the following style:

```
.LinkActionButtonDisabled
{
cursor: default;
color: inherit;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

this works in FF and chrome and IE10 upwards, but in IE8 and 9 the `filter: alpha(opacity=40);` doesn't seem to be applied. The other parts of the style are still in effect, for example the cursor defaults to the normal curosr rather than turning in to the link pointer cursor when hovering over. does anyone have any ie8 opacity issues like this?

Comment: You mention that IE9 doesn't work either, but IE9 supports the standard CSS `opacity` style, so the problem should be limited to IE8, unless IE9 is in the wrong mode. You might want to check that you're not in quirks mode or something like that.

Comment: For IE8 and earlier, the `filter` should work. Again, check the mode, as that may have a bearing. The `filter` style uses activeX to do its magic, so it is possible to disable `filter` if activeX is disabled (or if the relevant activeX control isn't installed -- unlikely, but I have seen it happen).

Comment: unfortunately I am forced into quirks mode, this is a very old site that was written completely for quirks mode

Comment: If the elements in question don't _have layout_, the styles won't get applied as expected. The site should be rendered in standards mode to get your properties to work.

Comment: `site that was written completely for quirks mode` For purpose? If not, change it.

Comment: @0xor1 - re quirks mode: Oh dear. That's got to hurt. If at all possible, I would recommend switching to use standards mode, especially if you need it to work the same in other browsers and newer IE versions (which have significant changes to quirks mode compared with IE8/9).

Comment: Switching from quirks mode to standards mode: easier than you'd think. Try adding `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` to the top of your CSS and `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your HTML. Voila: standards mode, but with quirks mode layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned in the comments, your site is build for *quirks mode*. I assume the elements in question don't `have layout`.

To get `opacity` and `filter` (and many others) to work, your site needs to render in standards mode.

Check out Spudley's comment about switching to standards mode:

> Switching from quirks mode to standards mode: easier than you'd think. Try adding `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` to the top of your CSS and `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your HTML. Voila: standards mode, but with quirks mode layout. – [Spudley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352765/spudley)